# How to use the latest version(3.0.83) of syntax highlighter written by Alex Gorbatchev?

Tags: javascript, html, css, syntaxhighlighter

I am trying to use syntax highlighter but it is not working.
Here is the hello, world sample.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/styles/shCore.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/styles/shThemeDefault.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shCore.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushCpp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
<pre class"brush:cpp;">
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, world!";
    return 0;
}
</pre>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //SyntaxHighlighter.config.bloggerMode = true;
        SyntaxHighlighter.all();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The syntax isn't getting highlighted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `=` after class.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/styles/shCore.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/styles/shThemeDefault.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shCore.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushCpp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
<pre class="brush:cpp;">
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, world!";
    return 0;
}
</pre>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //SyntaxHighlighter.config.bloggerMode = true;
        SyntaxHighlighter.all();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your ignorance is what was causing the problem, look at `<pre class="brush:cpp;">`

Comment: [output](http://jsbin.com/yudofuvali/1/edit?html,console,output) of the code working

Comment: In fact, my ignorance has no limits.